# How to return a list of time objects by looping through hours

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, datetime, time

I have been trying to figured out an algorithm to return a list of time based on a start time and end time and how many loop. For example the start time at 6 am and the end time at 10 pm and the looping number is 5 so I need to return 22-6 = 16 and 16/5 = 3.2 so I need to return

```
6:00:00
9:20:00
12:40:00
15:60:00
18:20:00
21:40:00
```

I need to return such these values. (Note, the return value I wrote are not accurate but just for the purpose of demonstration)

The current code:

```
// List<Time> times(int looping){
long test(){
    List<Time> result = new ArrayList<Time>();
    String start = "06:00:00";
    String finish = "22:00:00";

    Time startTime = Time.valueOf(start);
    Time endTime = Time.valueOf(finish);

    long totalHours = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();

    return totalHours;
   // return result;

}
```

Note: the long totalHours return a strange number not 16 and I'm not sure how to loop throw time and return the wanted values.

Comment: So basically you need to split a time interval into a given number of equal parts and produce a `List` of the start times of the parts, yes?

Comment: Yes so as the start time at 6 and the end time at 10pm  total hours between them are 16 hours so I need to split those 16 hours on 5 and return the list of start time of each thos 5

Comment: I was thinking to do a list of these 16 hours and loop throw them but it wont be accurate since the looping number won't be an abslote number like in these case it would be 3.2 so I need to give the start time every 3 hours and 20 minutes

Comment: Well, 3 hours and 12 minutes actually (16 hr = 960 min, 960 min / 5 = 192 min, 192 min = 3hr12 min).  The only question now is how to add an interval to a `Time` to find a new `Time`. Does your `Time` object give you any API that might help?

Comment: No it doesn't just to mention I'm using this code in android studio

Comment: What about `getTime()`; it probably returns milliseconds or microseconds. For your example of 192 minute interval, If you add 11,520,000ms (or 11,520,000,000ns), you now have the ms (or ns) for the start time of the next interval.  Can you turn that back into a `Time` (e.g., with  `new TIme(long millis)` or `Time.valueOf(long millis)`)?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Time`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. It was also never meant for anything else than transferring a time of day to or from an SQL database. Instead use `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

This is one of the places where java.time, the modern Java date and time API, excels. The method [`Duration::dividedBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#dividedBy(long)) does just want you want, dividing a span of time into a certain number of chunks.

```
    List<LocalTime> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String start = "06:00:00";
    String finish = "22:00:00";

    LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse(start);
    LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse(finish);

    Duration totalTime = Duration.between(startTime, endTime);
    int subintervalCount = 5;
    Duration subintervalLength = totalTime.dividedBy(subintervalCount);

    LocalTime currentTime = startTime;
    for (int i = 0; i < subintervalCount; i++) {
        result.add(currentTime);
        currentTime = currentTime.plus(subintervalLength);
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

This outputs:

> [06:00, 09:12, 12:24, 15:36, 18:48]

### Where did the strange number of total hours come from?

> the long totalHours return a strange number not 16 and I'm not sure
>   how to loop throw time and return the wanted values.

The `Time` class doesn’t define a `getTime` method. Instead you are calling the `getTime` method of the superclass `java.util.Date`, another poorly designed and long outdated class that we should no longer use. This `getTime` retunrs the count of *milliseconds*  since the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC, something that does not make sense for a time of day. I consider it likely that your subtraction yielded the number of milliseconds rather than the number of hours between your two times.

Edit: In case you’re curious and want to check: 16 hours equals 57 600 000 milliseconds. I obtained the number from `TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(16)`.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.